# Сложный ORDER BY в MySQL запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе данных есть список объявлений. У каждого объявления есть `user_id` (автор объявления) и `flag`.

Необходимо вывести сперва объявления с `user_id = 7, 9, 12`, затем вывести объявления у которых в базе `flag = 1`, остальные объявления вывести в порядке убывания `id`.

```
SELECT * FROM info ORDER BY ...
```

Другая сложность состоит в том, что в запросе стоит limit 10, так как оставшиеся объявления подгружаются аяксом порциями по 10 (lazyload).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно применить немного магии и выполнить такой запрос:

```
SELECT id, IF(id IN (7, 9, 12), 1, IF(flag = 1, 2, 3)) group_info FROM info ORDER BY group_info, id;
```

Код на [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86516/1)

Answer (score 4):

Стандартное решение:

```
SELECT *
FROM info
ORDER BY case when id IN (7, 9, 12) then 1 when flag = 1 then 2 else 3 end, id desc;
```