# SQL, задать свою последовательнотсь для ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Как изменить последовательность для `ORDER BY` что-бы выдавала не `['a', 'b', 'c']`, a `['b', 'с', 'a']`

---

Пример:

Есть таблица вида:

```
+----+----------------+
| id |  type          |
+----+----------------+
| 1  |  contracts     |
| 2  |  notifications |
| 3  |  protocols     |
+----+----------------+
```

И нужно получить таблицу типа:

```
+----+----------------+
| id |  type          |
+----+----------------+
| 2  |  notifications |
| 3  |  protocols     |
| 1  |  contracts     |
+----+----------------+
```

При сортировки `notifications` всегда в центре (логично в общем, но интересно как можно задать свою последовательность):

```
> SELECT * FROM my_tabel ORDER BY type; 

+----+----------------+
| id |  type          |
+----+----------------+
| 1  |  contracts     |
| 2  |  notifications |
| 3  |  protocols     |
+----+----------------+
```

---

Как вариант можно просто сделать 3 запроса к базе, но возможно это можно сделать 1 запросом к `SQL`?

Comment: проще в этой или другой таблице сделать колонку где указать порядок сортировки

Comment: @Mike можно, но в таблице 348049 записей, и легче сделать 3 запроса к базе чем еще 1 поле

Comment: Либо if писать как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517840/ или тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/273608

Comment: Если группы действительно всего 3 - то развернуть IF или как я и сказал в первом комментарии _сделать другую таблицу_ в которой будет 2 поля: ваш type и его порядок выдачи, переклеится с этой таблице в запросе и собственно по колонке из нее отсортировать

Comment: @Mike вообще решил при помощи IF `SELECT * FROM my_tabel ORDER BY IF (type = 'notifications', 'contracts', 'protocols');`

Comment: странное решение оно вам в разнобой выдаст protocols и contracts потому как вместо обоих значений даст одно и то же - protocols

Comment: @Mike да, спасибо, очень странно вывод получился, c IF, сейчас корректно: `SELECT * FROM my_tabel ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'notifications', 'contracts', 'protocols');`